# Server is sending data incorrectly

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

Hi i am just starting to use express.js and nodejs and ran into a problem, my server is sending markup to me without css and js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const io = new Server(server);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '\\client\\dist\\index.html');
});
```

my file structure:

[image]

and error:
[image]

Comment: You must set up your express app to serve static files, in your case from your `dist` subdirectory.  [Read this](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

Comment: I'll post that as an answer however I will give credit to you, @O.Jones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set up your express app to serve static files, in your case from your dist subdirectory. [Read this](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

The line of code looks like this:

```
 app.use(express.static('dist'))
```